# Synergy 32bit and 64bit incompatibility problems

Tags: windows-7, synergy

I'm having problems with 64bit server and two 32bit clients. The problem stems from error-2. Server in center, 32bit clients on each side. Mouse switch is set to happen on double-tap edge. Changing to immediate does not make any changes to symptoms.

The symptoms, two of them:

Right side changes at around 2/5 width instead of right edge, no matter what resolution server uses. Left side works fine. Right side changes between 32bit clients without any problems. In fact, everything works between 32bit server and clients but newest builds don't allow 32bit to be installed on 64bit system. Now i have it as: server left -> client XP left -> client Win7. 32bit versions switch correctly on any side. Also trying top or bottom edge on 64bit server does the same, it changes at 2/5 top or 2/5 bottom, respectively, only left side works.

When using video on server, it does not work properly (also can happen sporadically with for ex FireFox, usually with some video screen). Mouse cursor disappears from server as expected but does not appear on client screen. When using right mouse click, it shows the invoked menu at the bottom right corner on client screen but without mouse cursor. My guess is that the mouse exist in "limbo", between the two screens but on client side. Only way out is to press ctrl-alt-del that brings back the mouse cursor to the server. This symptom goes away on it's own when switching focus to some other application and only after few minutes. Restarting server or client does not help.

I do a lot of product testing, mainly software and webdesign. It is integral that i have win7 64bit, win7 32bit and winxp 32bit. Synergy has provided me a lot of freedom but this latest behavior really hinders my workflow, specially since due to the XP machine role, it does not have a keyboard at all...

I kept an earlier version for long time and updated  to 1.4.17. Reverting back 1.4.12 does not help, which is very odd as that version worked fine. I'm installing daily (or nightly, if that's the preferred term..) builds and hoping for a solution.

Server is HP laptop with ATI X1600 Mobile GPU, Win7Ulitmate 64bit, left side XP32Bit ATI GPU (forgot what it was, some 256MB passive cooling, ie at least 6y old...) and right side Win7 32bit Ultimate NVidia GTX260.